# How to get progressively closer to value of 1.0, in a PHP loop using the number of items in the array

Tags: php, arrays

If anyone has any suggestions on improvements to the Question wording I'm happy to update it.

Basically I'm after increasing opacity of a label so the last label is the darkest / most opaque

I've got an array of labels and I want to set the opacity variable to be fractionally higher on each iteration,

If I had 10 items, I could simply do

```
foreach ($labels as $key => $label) {
    $this->renderLabel($label, $opacity = $key + 1 / 10);
}
```

This would give me

```
First Label (0.1)
Second Label (0.2)
Third Label (0.3)
...
```

But I can have an unknown number of labels, and just know they need to get progressively more opaque so the last label is always `1.0` and the first label is `0.Something`

Comment: `(1.0 - 0.Something) / N` where N is the number of elements. This gives you the step

Comment: @Cid please do not intentionally break Stack Overflow page design by providing answers as comments.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/352329

Comment: @mickmackusa I VTC, that's why I didn't answer but comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the comment and some help.

Can divide the `$key + 1` by the count of items.

```
<?php

$labels = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
$count = count($labels);

foreach ($labels as $key => $label) {
    printf("%s %f\n", $label, ($key +1) / $count);
}

// Outputs
One 0.250000
Two 0.500000
Three 0.750000
Four 1.000000
```